# presentation of a family of solvable groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, solvable-groups

I am looking for a family of finite solvable groups (with infinite members) with given presentations. I am aware that for example dihedral groups, or dicyclic groups have well-known presentations. Also, certain 2-groups have been constructed using generators and relations. However, I need a family of whose members are solvable but not supersolvable. Any reference to such structures will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a finite solvable group, and let $V$ be an irreducible $F[X]$-module over some finite field $F$. Then in most cases the affine group $V \rtimes X$ is a finite solvable group which is not supersolvable. (Since $V$ is minimal normal in $V \rtimes X$, and usually not cyclic).

Given generators and relations for $X$ and the action of generators of $X$ on $V$, you can construct a presentation of $V \rtimes X$.